# Creating a Stream User in React Native with a Rails Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, getstream-io

I am trying to create a stream user for my react native front end.  I used Ruby on Rails for the authentication backend, received a jwt token, and now I want to use that token to create my stream user.  How do I go about doing this?  In creating the token server-side, would I need to include this line of code in my login/signup function?

```
user_token = client.create_user_session_token('the-user-id')
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating and passing a token from your Ruby back end to your react-native front end, you need to instantiate the Stream client in your front end. You don't need to create another token on the front end with the code you have linked. Instantiate client with the following code:

```
const client = stream.connect(api_key, token, app_id);
```

Comment: My pleasure. Check out this blog post on stream and auth too
https://getstream.io/blog/tutorial-user-auth-with-stream-chat-feeds/